# Checking the clickability of an element in selenium using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I've been trying to write a script which will give me all the links to the episodes present on this page :- http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/episodes

As you can see that the links can be seen in 'Outer HTML', I used selenium and PhantomJS with python.

Link Example: http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time

However, I can't seem to get my code right. I do have a basic Idea of what I want to do. Here's the process :-

1.) Copy the Outer HTML of the very first page and then save it as 'Source_html' file.

2.) Look for links inside this file.

3.) Move to the next page to see rest of the videos and their links.

4.) Repeat the step 2.

This is what my code looks like :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/episodes')

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")


source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
f = open('source_code.html', 'w')
f.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()

print 'Links On First Page Are : \n'
soup = BeautifulSoup('source_code.html')
subtitles = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'popup-heading'})
official = 'something'

for official in subtitles:
        x = official.findAll('a')
        for a in x:
            print a['href']


sbtn = driver.find_element_by_link_text(">"):
print sbtn

print 'Entering The Loop Now'
for driver.find_element_by_link_text(">"):
    sbtn.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
    source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    f = open('source_code1.html', 'w')
    f.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
```

Things I already know :-

`soup = BeautifulSoup('source_code.html')` won't work, because I need to open this file via python and feed it into BS after that. That I can manage.

That `official` variable isn't really doing anything. Just helping me start a loop.

```
for driver.find_element_by_link_text(">"):
```

Now, this is what I need to fix somehow. I'm not sure how to check if this thing is still clickable or not. If yes, then proceed to next page, get the links, click this again to go to page 3 and repeat the process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `BeautifulSoup` here at all. Just grab all the links via `selenium`. Proceed to next page only if the `>` link is visible. Here is the complete implementation including gathering the links, necessary waits. It should work for any page count:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/episodes")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

links = []
while True:
    # wait for the page to load
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.item-title")))

    # wait until the loading circle becomes invisible
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "loadingCircle")))

    links.extend([link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.item-title")])

    print("Parsing page number #" + driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.jp-current").text)

    # click next
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.next")
    if not next_link.is_displayed():
        break

    next_link.click()
    time.sleep(1)  # hardcoded delay

print(len(links))
print(links)
```

For the mentioned in the question URL, it prints:

```
Parsing page number #1
Parsing page number #2
93
['http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/assassination-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/assassination-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/assassination-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/baseball-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/baseball-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/baseball-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/grown-up-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/grown-up-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/grown-up-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/assembly-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/assembly-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/assembly-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/test-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/test-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/test-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/school-trip-time1st-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/school-trip-time1st-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/school-trip-time1st-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/school-trip-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/school-trip-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/school-trip-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/transfer-student-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/transfer-student-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/transfer-student-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/l-and-r-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/l-and-r-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/l-and-r-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/transfer-student-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/transfer-student-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/transfer-student-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/ball-game-tournament-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/ball-game-tournament-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/ball-game-tournament-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/talent-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/talent-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/talent-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/vision-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/vision-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/vision-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/end-of-term-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/end-of-term-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/end-of-term-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/schools-out1st-term', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/schools-out1st-term', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/schools-out1st-term', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/island-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/island-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/island-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/action-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/action-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/action-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/pandemonium-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/pandemonium-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/pandemonium-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/karma-time2nd-period', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/deadman-wonderland', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/deadman-wonderland', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/riddle-story-of-devil', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/riddle-story-of-devil', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/soul-eater', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/soul-eater', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/xx-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/xx-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/xx-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/nagisa-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/nagisa-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/nagisa-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/summer-festival-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/summer-festival-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/summer-festival-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/kaede-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/kaede-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/kaede-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/itona-horibe-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/itona-horibe-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/itona-horibe-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/spinning-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/spinning-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/spinning-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/leader-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/leader-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/assassination-classroom/videos/official/leader-time', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/deadman-wonderland', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/deadman-wonderland', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/riddle-story-of-devil', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/riddle-story-of-devil', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/soul-eater', 'http://www.funimation.com/shows/soul-eater']
```

Comment: Oh god, I cannot thank you enough for this. I'll need to understand your code first,though. Could you please explain a little about your `links.extend([link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.item-title")])` line?

Comment: @user2408212 sure, this is the "heart" of the code that collects the links. Here we are locating the `a` elements with `item-title` class and getting the list of `href` attributes which we then put into a `links` list. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your code is working like a charm. Now, I have to figure out how to remove the extra links. If you see my code, the `for official in subtitles:` thing is getting me just the links I need (Duplicate Entries, though).

Comment: @user2408212 ah, sure, try the `div.popup-heading a` instead of `a.item-title` CSS selector.

Comment: Giving 'None'. Tell me one thing though. I'm thinking of checking the urls for a particular string. If the URL matches that particular string, then keep it. How does that sound?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I use `webelement.is_displayed()` to check if it is clickable or not.

```
isLinkDisplay = driver.find_element_by_link_text(">").is_displayed()
```